# Partial RSA Decrypter

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

I have a program that can encrypt and partially decrypt a number with RSA-1024 algorithm.

For encryption:

`C = M^e mod n`

But for decryption, result will be mod 256:

`partialM = (C^d mod n) % 256`

Also I know `e = 65537`, `d = constant`, `n = constant` so will not be changed after multiple runs of program.
I want to know if it's possible for a given C to find M. If yes, how?

Comment: What do you mean by  d=ct and n=ct?  It makes no sense:  d cannot be the same as n.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question. It could be on-topic at crypto.stackexchange.com. Even there, you're expected to show some attempt to solve the problem on your own. One hint: take advantage of RSA's multiplicative property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but not easy.

There is a well-known attack against RSA called Least Significant Bit Oracle Attack. Shortly speaking, if you are provided with a blackbox you can ask for the parity bit of the plaintext for any chosen ciphertext, you will be able to reveal complete plaintext.

You can find the whole attack description [in this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/11053).

To sum it up: you cannot break the cipher for a single known ciphertext - partial plaintext pair without access to the oracle. However, you should never reveal any bits of plaintext - knowledge of a single bit for enough plaintexts can cause a real damage.